# Setting values from ACCESS database as labels in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbconnection

I want to add data from my Access database to a `label`. the data was searched using a query on `FORM1`.

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ty\Documents\Uni\Level6\Project\App\software\Databases\Boards.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand commandBoards = new OleDbCommand();
commandBoards.Connection = connection;
string queryBoardsLength = "select * from [Boards] where [Length] >=" + TxtLength.Text;
string queryBoardsWidth = "select * from [Boards] where [Width] >=" + TxtWidth.Text;
commandBoards.CommandText = queryBoardsLength;
commandBoards.CommandText = queryBoardsWidth;
OleDbDataReader readerBoards = commandBoards.ExecuteReader();

while (readerBoards.Read())
{
    ComBoards.Items.Add(readerBoards["ID"].ToString());
}
```

this populated a combo box on `FORM1` with the search results. I then set the selected result from the combo box as a variable when it is selected.

```
private void ComBoards_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Boards = this.ComBoards.GetItemText(this.ComBoards.SelectedItem);
}
```

On `FORM2` I ran a similar query to gather the exact data from the Access database based on the selected `ID`. I want to display the length as a `label`.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblBoardname.Text = Form1.Boards;
    OleDbConnection connectionBoards = new OleDbConnection();
    connectionBoards.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ty\Documents\Uni\Level6\Project\App\software\Databases\Boards.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    connectionBoards.Open();
    OleDbCommand commandBoardsget = new OleDbCommand();
    commandBoardsget.Connection = connectionBoards;
    string queryBoardsget = "select * from [Boards] where [ID] =" + lblBoardname;
    commandBoardsget.CommandText = queryBoardsget;
    OleDbDataReader readerBoardsget = commandBoardsget.ExecuteReader();
    while (readerBoardsget.Read())
    {
        lblBoardsizel.Text = readerBoardsget["Length"].ToString();
    }
```

Everything works apart from the `Reader` on `FORM2` where I get the following error:

> Syntax error (comma) in query expression '[ID]=System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text: Rhino Boards'.

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can understand this comment. If in case you can, please read your error message it says clearly you are passing the entire label object instead of the text value of it. [ID] =" + lblBoardname; should be [ID] =" + lblBoardname.Text;

Comment: Hi thanks for spotting that... simple error. However i'm still getting and error. "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[ID] =Rhino Boards"